# performSegueWithIdentifier and popViewControllerAnimated breaking screen navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have 4 ViewControllers A, B, C, D. I move from A->B->C->D using `Push Segues` created from Storyboard.

Due to the logic of my app, if the user wants to go back from Screen D, screen C is no longer valid and I redirect the user to Screen C by using `performSegueWithIdentifier`

The problem starts now - I can't move back from Screen B->A using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

I would like to know why is this happening and how can I address such a scenario & fix the navigation?

Comment: This is happening, because instead of poping from D to B, you are using a modal segue. This will not produce the desired result. Most likely, it is just creating another instance of B and is presenting it as modal view controller on top of everything. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of segue that you use?

Why don't you use:

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can access the stack of view controllers using the `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController`.

Here is [Apple's documentation on UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW5)

Comment: For normal forward screen navigation I use `Push Segue` created from Storyboard. For moving back from D->B, I created a `Modal Segue` by connecting my ViewController D to ViewController B (using Flip Horizontal) and gave it a name which I used in `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: You should not mix nav controller and modal segues the way you do. Try the method I suggest.

Comment: May I know why do you say this can't be mixed?

Comment: Yes, you may. When you present a modal view controller, you are actually escaping the current navigation tree/structure. A good example is when you use it as a user guide screen or presenting something and dismissing it when you are done. Your use case is totally different. All you need to do is pop 2 view controllers from the navigation stack instead of one. I suggest you do some research on the difference between `UINavigationController` navigation and `Modal View Controller` navigation.